# Unix Semaphore - unable to set initial value

Tags: c++, semaphore

I am trying to initiate a UNIX semaphore so that I can use it to control two processes.

I copied the `sem_init` function from [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-semaphore/index.html#listing2) example. I removed the `pshared` parameter because it was not used in the function and corrected `int * sem` to `int * semid` assuming this was a mistake.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* The semaphore key is an arbitrary long integer which serves as an
   external identifier by which the semaphore is known to any program
   that wishes to use it. */

using namespace std;

#define KEY (1492)

int sem_init(int* semid, unsigned int value) {
    /* get the semaphore */
    *semid = semget(KEY, 1, IPC_CREAT);
    if (*semid == -1) {
        printf("Unable to obtain semaphore.\n");
        return -1;
    } 

    int ret = semctl( *semid, 0, SETVAL, value);
    if (ret == -1) {
        printf("Unable to set semaphore value: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(void) {
    int* semid = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    sem_init(semid, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

The program prints `Unable to set semaphore value: permission denied`. I also copied the first main function from [this](https://gist.github.com/vladimir-lu/1148426) example and it prints `Cannot set semaphore value`.

One thing I should mention is that there does seem to be processes running in the background from previous times that I have run the program, but it won't let me terminate them (it says operation not permitted), so maybe the semaphore is already initialized and it won't let me reinitialize it?

Also another thing. The first example passes `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666` to `sem_get`, but when I do this `semget` returns -1. It only works if just `IPC_CREAT` is passed.

If you could let me know what the `0666` does that would be great because none of the examples explain it.

Comment: What is the value of `errno` after `semctl()` fails?

Comment: Read up on `errno`, `strerror()` and `perror()` so you can improve your error messages with information about *what* the error is.

Comment: The article to which you link is about implementing the POSIX semaphore API in terms of the older System V API.  Are you using one of the very few systems that support the latter but not the former?  Otherwise, why not use the POSIX semaphore implementation already provided to you?

Comment: @AndrewHenle @Shawn I printed `strerror(errno)` and it says `permission denied`.

Comment: Also, [sem_init()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html) is a function in the newer POSIX semaphore api. You shouldn't be using that name for your own function.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am doing this for an assignment where they said we had to use UNIX semaphores.

Comment: The term "UNIX semaphores" does not distinguish between the two implementations, but I'll take you to mean that you are required to use the SystemV interface.  In that case, it seems a bit roundabout to implement the POSIX interface on top.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah, they said to use "UNIX semaphores" instead of "POSIX semaphores". They said we have to use `semget`, `semctl` and `semop`. But we have to use it same way we would a POSIX one, so I guess they just want us to be familiar with both since we used POSIX is the last assignment.

Comment: Does the semaphore, by chance, already exist?  You can see what semaphores exist on your system on the command-line with `ipcs -s`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons This is was I suspected. There actually are quite a few running right now, but all have owners with different student IDs than mine (since I am running this on my school's server). They all have `perms` of 666, so is this was the `0666` means in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The program prints `Unable to set semaphore value: permission denied`.

That would be because in the event that the `semget()` call you present in fact creates a new semaphore set, it creates it with no access permissions for anyone.  You probably want something more like this:

```
*semid = semget(KEY, 1, IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

That will assign mode 0600; add more permissions as needed.  The `S_` macros are documented with the `open()` function.

> One thing I should mention is that there does seem to be processes
>   running in the background from previous times that I have run the
>   program, but it won't let me terminate them (it says operation not
>   permitted), so maybe the semaphore is already initialized and it won't
>   let me reinitialize it?

I don't see any reason why the particular program you presented would continue running in the background, but any semaphore set it creates has kernel persistence: it lives until explicitly removed, which will be past your particular program's termination.  You should be able to use the `ipcs` command to get a list of current semaphores, and the `ipcrm` command to remove old ones.  These may require root privilege.

> The first example passes `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666` to `sem_get`,
>   but when I do this semget returns -1. It only works if just
>   `IPC_CREAT` is passed.

This is again the issue that your semaphore set outlives the program.  When you specify `IPC_EXCL`, you are explicitly requesting that the call fail (returning -1) if a semaphore set with the specified key already exists, and therefore is not created fresh by the call.  It should not be harmful to include the mode bits (the `0666`) when omitting `IPC_EXCL`, but they have effect only when a new semaphore set is created.  The `S_IRUSR` and `S_IWUSR` constants I referenced above represent two of the specific mode bits, and in general I recommend using the constants over encoding the mode numerically.

As an aside, note that the `ftok()` function is the conventional means to obtain a key value with which to identify a semaphore set.

Comment: So I tried `IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR` but now `semget` return -1 with the error `Permission denied`. Again I am now running this on my own computer (not my school's server) and `ipcs -s` does not list any semaphores.

Comment: I ran it with administrator priveledges on my computer and it seems to work, but it doesn't work on my school's server. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The problems with

```
*semid = semget(KEY, 1, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666);
```

and

```
int ret = semctl( *semid, 0, SETVAL, value);
```

are almost certainly caused because the Sys V semaphore identified by `*semid` already exists with incorrect permissions, likely because an earlier creation left off the `0666` permissions.  Since the semaphore id already exists, you can't attach to it with the `IPC_EXCL` flag set.

Assuming you're running on Linux, [the `ipcs -s` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ipcs.1.html) will show you the existing Sys V semaphores.  You can then use [the `ipcrm` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ipcrm.1.html) to remove the semaphore(s) with incorrect permissions and start over.

Comment: So now I am running this on my own linux distribution but when I call `semget` with `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666`, the `errno` that returns is 17 which mean `File exists`. But when I call `ipcs -s`, nothing is listed.

Comment: @alexanderd5398 That's strange.  What's the output from `ipcs -a` or `ipcs -s id ID`, where `ID` is the id held in `*semid`?

Comment: `ipcs -a` printed three empty lists. The `semid` returned by `semget` is always 1, and `ipcs -s id 1` prints the same thing as `ipcs -s` (an empty list).